# Run SAP GUI script in the background (not visible)

Tags: sap-gui

I am writing a code using SAP GUI Scripting API to automate some tasks in the SAP GUI for Windows, but I need to hide the screens.

Is there such thing as a `visible = false` option?

If there is not, how can I do it?

Context: the SAP GUI Scripting API is called from VBA in Microsoft Outlook but is valid for any language automating SAP GUI via SAP GUI Scripting API.

Comment: not clear, what are you want from SAP, just read the data from it thro RFC, or trying to insert/update some SAP data?

Comment: Insert data, fill fields

Comment: did you try to use WScript.Shell?

Comment: I did not, would it be possible?

Answer (score 4):

Thank you all.

I figured it out, just needed to add

```
.findById("wnd[0]").iconify
```

Thanks again

Comment: Does anyone know how can I apply this command "findById("wnd[0]").iconify"   to the pop-ups windows?
I tried changing wnd[0]  for  wnd[1]  but it did not work

Comment: Apologies for the late comment, if you didn't figure it out I think you may have to use `Application.SendKeys("{ENTER}")` from VBA. This will click the "Enter" key. However, this will only work when the popup window is activated.

Answer (score 0):

You can automate Outlook from any application without displaying Outlook UI. See [How to automate Outlook from another program](https://support.microsoft.com/kb/201096?wa=wsignin1.0) for more information.

Also you may find the [Using Automation to Send a Microsoft Outlook Message](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/161088) article helpful.

Comment: Not quite what I expected... It is SAP that I don't want to display. Outlook is fine

Comment: @levys That isn't particularly clear in your question, made more apparent by the fact that this answer exists. Perhaps you could edit your question to be more clear?

Comment: I think I was not clear enough. I have a code in Outlook VBA and it is working just fine. It automates a SAP process. The thing is: I want SAP Screen to be updated in the end of the process, and NOT while the process is running. It would be something similar to Application.ScreenUpdate = False in VBA

Answer (score 0):

from my expirience, I know two options of running SAP script, the first one is using WScript.Shell, I know that there is too much information against this method, try to search about it

```
Sub test()
    Dim Wsh
    Set Wsh = CreateObject("WScript.Shell").Run("C:\Users\USERNAME\Desktop\Script1.vbs")
End Sub
```

this method is allow to launch applications in your PC, e.g.:

```
Sub test2()
    Dim Wsh As Object
    Set Wsh = CreateObject("WScript.Shell").Exec("calc.exe")
End Sub
```

the second one of running script, is the launch the code from script in MS office without *.vbs file, as in example bellow

```
Option Explicit

Public SapGuiAuto As Object
Public ApplicationSAP As Object
Public Connection As Object
Public Session As Object

Sub start()
Set SapGuiAuto = GetObject("SAPGUI")
Set ApplicationSAP = SapGuiAuto.GetScriptingEngine
Set Connection = ApplicationSAP.Children(0)
Set Session = Connection.Children(0)

Session.findById("wnd[0]").maximize             ' max main SAP window
Session.findById("wnd[0]/tbar[0]/okcd").Text = "/n" & "IW33"    'Transaction code
Session.findById("wnd[0]").sendVKey 0               'start transaction

End Sub
```

I hope it will help you in further searching of the required information

Comment: I think I was not clear enough.
I have a code in Outlook VBA and it is working just fine.
It automates a SAP process.
The thing is: I want SAP Screen to be updated in the end of the process, and NOT while the process is running.
It would be something similar to Application.ScreenUpdate = False  in VBA

Comment: @levys Maybe I'm wrong, but when you use scripts, you will hardly be able to turn off screen updating for the SAP window. But you can use other methods of updating the SAP data. without using the SAP window, e.g. connection to SAP using RFC BAPI Call, but in this case you need to know functional module which is behind transaction-code. the second method which is might help you, is the using of GuiXT.

Answer (score 0):

You could try the following: session.TestToolMode = 1

Regards,
ScriptMan

Answer (score 0):

You can connect to your server through `OpenConnection` or `OpenConnectionByConnectionString` using `/INPLACE` at the end of the connection string.

Resuming... Instead of use something like `conn = scripting_engine.Children( 0 )`, try to use something like:

```
conn = scripting_engine.OpenConnection( 'MYSAPCONNECTION /INPLACE' )
session = conn.Children( 0 )
```

By the away... See more at [**this**](http://www.synactive.com/download/sap%20gui%20scripting/sap%20gui%20scripting%20api.pdf) link.

Answer (score 0):

I have ultimate answer, that is working for me. Just create new Sub and Call your Sub that contains SAP Script. Excel screen is always on and SAP is working in the background.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).